# Rails Mysql - find all values starting with white spacing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I compose a query that finds all the values of a specific model that start with a whitespace?

Say I have a model:
Country with one field value.

And say I have 3 records in the table:
"China"
"United States"
" Argentina"

I want to compose a query to find " Argentina" (starts with a whitespace).

Comment: Please include the table structure, relevant values, and the code you already tried. I didn't downvote your question but I guess including a [mcve] will revert it

Comment: added. Haven't tried any code as dont know how to compose a query with "starts_with?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:
`Country.where("name like ' %'")`

you can find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions)

Comment: That doesnt match my requirement. I want to find all the countries that start with a whitespace. That query will find all the countries that their value contains the word Argentina.

Comment: Worked for me :)